# How safe is file_get_contents() while retrieving a local file path, not user inputted

Tags: php, file, security, file-io, file-get-contents

I have user inputted HTML content stored on files without extension, on system-named folders and not user named files.

```
>    file_put_contents($DBStoredFolder.'/'.$DBStoredFilename, $UserInputHtml);
```

How safe is to retrieve the content and print it?

```
>    $content = file_get_contents($DBStoredFolder.'/'.$DBStoredFilename);
>    echo '<html><body>'.$content.'</body></html>';
```

Can a file without extension only accessed via file_get_contents on a fixed path and then echoed, run PHP code?

I know that the returning html needs to be secured when it runs on the browser but that is other thing.

Comment: Thank you, I have did my research and also seen a lot of questions on SO but always referencing to the path and filename, but not on the content. Since PHP docs says it only returns the result as a string and it's path is server determined, i thought its a safe way. Do you have any suggestion on how to improve it?

Comment: @PaulCrovella Its also what I need, but i want to be sure that file_get_contents only returns the file on a string and doesnt execute any code (Example: eval();) and maybe htmlentities() isnt enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to answer that question generally.

If you're completely in control of the filename (i.e., there's no possibility of user input interfering with the filename), then it's safe to open the file at that path.

If you're completely in control of the contents of the file (i.e., it couldn't possibly be a user-uploaded or user-edited file) then it's safe to display it.

If you're completely in control of the formatting in the file and can be sure that it's already HTML, then there's no need to escape or sanitize the contents before displaying.

Almost always, though, one or more of those assumptions isn't really valid. How you cope with the uncertainty depends entirely on the specifics of the situation. In general, sanitize the filename, sanitize the file contents, sanitize the display, sanitize everything.

Personally, I'd rather be overly cautious with a filename I do control than risk introducing user input without realizing it.

Comment: I´m in complete control of the filename, but not on the content since it has to accept user-edited HTML and JS. Im also on the prevention side, thats why I want to be surethat file_get_contents only returns the file on a string and doesnt execute any code in between [Ex: eval(); ]. In that case htmlentities() on the file isnt enough.

Comment: PHP only does things you tell it to do. If you don't run `eval()`, it doesn't eval. The danger isn't that PHP will suddenly run code all on its own; it's that displaying tainted file contents in a browser will then render and execute whatever that file says to do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can a file without extension  only accessed via file_get_contents en then echoed,  run  PHP code? I know that the returning html needs to be secured when it runs on the browser but that is other thing.thanks again!